# Display multiple videos in a switch case

Tags: swift

I am trying to pass videos into a switch case statement. e.g. when you click on each cocktail it should load a different video, however I am getting a bad thread execution error. I need to somehow find a way to implement the videos onto each cocktail and make sure these are different. Below is the code for this class. Help would be much appreciated.

```
var passdata: String = ""

var toPass:String!
var cocktails = ["Mojito","Long Island Iced Tea","Sex On The Beach","Screaming Orgasum","Cosmo","Strawberry Summer Sling","Rosini Royal","Blue Lagoon"]


@IBOutlet weak var labelpassdata: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!

var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
var playerView = AVPlayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    passdata = cocktails[0]
    switch toPass
    {
    case cocktails[0]:
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/marcusgriffiths/Desktop/iosApp 2/MrCocktailsMenu/How to Make a Mojito  Cocktail Recipes.mp4")

    WebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width = \"\(self.WebView.frame.width) \"height = \"\(self.WebView.frame.height)\" src = \"\(fileURL)\"> </iframe>", baseURL: nil)
    case cocktails[1]:
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/marcusgriffiths/Desktop/iosApp 2/MrCocktailsMenu/How To Make The Long Island Iced Tea - Bartender Style.mp4")

    WebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width = \"\(self.WebView.frame.width) \"height = \"\(self.WebView.frame.height)\" src = \"\(fileURL)\"> </iframe>", baseURL: nil)
case cocktails[2]:
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/marcusgriffiths/Desktop/iosApp 2/MrCocktailsMenu/Sex on the Beach Vodka Cocktail _ Joel Fraser.mp4")

    WebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width = \"\(self.WebView.frame.width) \"height = \"\(self.WebView.frame.height)\" src = \"\(fileURL)\"> </iframe>", baseURL: nil)
case cocktails[3]:
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/marcusgriffiths/Desktop/iosApp 2/MrCocktailsMenu/(Screaming) Orgasm - Drink Recipe.mp4")

    WebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width = \"\(self.WebView.frame.width) \"height = \"\(self.WebView.frame.height)\" src = \"\(fileURL)\"> </iframe>", baseURL: nil)
case cocktails[4]:
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/marcusgriffiths/Desktop/iosApp 2/MrCocktailsMenu/How to make a Cosmopolitan cocktail - by Cointreau.mp4")

    WebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width = \"\(self.WebView.frame.width) \"height = \"\(self.WebView.frame.height)\" src = \"\(fileURL)\"> </iframe>", baseURL: nil)
case cocktails[5]:
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/marcusgriffiths/Desktop/iosApp 2/MrCocktailsMenu/Strawberry Sling Alcoholic Video Recipe Thermochef cheekyricho.mp4")

    WebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width = \"\(self.WebView.frame.width) \"height = \"\(self.WebView.frame.height)\" src = \"\(fileURL)\"> </iframe>", baseURL: nil)
case cocktails[6]:
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/marcusgriffiths/Desktop/iosApp 2/MrCocktailsMenu/Rossini Cocktail _ Jamie Oliver.mp4")

    WebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width = \"\(self.WebView.frame.width) \"height = \"\(self.WebView.frame.height)\" src = \"\(fileURL)\"> </iframe>", baseURL: nil)
case cocktails[7]:
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "")

    WebView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width = \"\(self.WebView.frame.width) \"height = \"\(self.WebView.frame.height)\" src = \"\(fileURL)\"> </iframe>", baseURL: nil)

          passdata = cocktails[0]
    default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: You are switching on toPass which is never actually set from what I can see.